# Count the number of unique characters in a string

Tags: r, string, count

I have a *dataframe* where one of the columns is of type string.
I would like to count the number of unique/distinct characters in that string.

eg.

```
"banana" -> 3
'he' -> 2
```

A reproducible example:

I have a data frame where a column is type string. I would need to filter out those rows where the string has only one distinct character.

```
col1         col2       col3 
new york
qqqq
melbourne
aaaaaa
```

I would need to have a final data frame like

```
col1      col2    col3 
new york
melbourne
```

So delete those rows completely.

Comment: `length(unique(strsplit("banana", "")[[1]]))`

Comment: In the new dataset, `melbourne` has 2 `e`

Comment: indeed, but I don't want to delete any word with a letter repeated. I want to delete words with all the letter being the same. The reason is: there are many people that to avoid give that data put few characters like 'aaaaa' and I would like to mark that as invalid in my systems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use `str_count`

```
library(stringr)
sum(!!str_count(str1, letters))
#[1] 3
```

#### Update

Using the new dataset

```
i1 <- !sapply(df1$col1, function(x) any(str_count(x, letters)>1))
df1[i1,,drop=FALSE]
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "banana"
```

Comment: "characters" is not necessarily `letters`

Comment: @hrbrmstr  It is true, but at least in the example showed by the OP, it is letters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I apply data<- data[sum(!!str_count(df$my_column, letters))!=1,]  returns all the rows

Comment: @DroppingOff Actually the `sum(...)` part is just the sum of the unique characters in the string.  Can you please update your post with a reproducible example

Comment: added an example now

Comment: What does `!!` mean?

Comment: @Nip it is double negation `v1 <- 1:5; v1 == 5; !(v1 == 5); !!(v1 == 5)`

Comment: Is there a regex for `letters` set? I mean using a regex instead of the `letters` object to get the same results.

Answer (score 11):

This makes no assumption about "characters" being in `letters` and avoids making R data structures:

```
library(inline)

.char_unique_code <- "
std::vector < std::string > s = as< std::vector < std::string > >(x);
unsigned int input_size = s.size();

std::vector < std::string > chrs(input_size);

for (unsigned int i=0; i<input_size; i++) {

  std::string t = s[i];

  for (std::string::iterator chr=t.begin();
       chr != t.end(); ++chr) {

    if (chrs[i].find(*chr) == std::string::npos) {
      chrs[i] += *chr;
    }

  }

}
return(wrap(chrs));
"

char_unique <- 
  rcpp(sig=signature(x="std::vector < std::string >"),
       body=.char_unique_code,
       includes=c("#include <string>",
                 "#include <iostream>"))

nchar(char_unique("banana"))
## [1] 3
```

Why avoid making R lists?

```
library(stringr)
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

str_char_ct_unique <- function(x) sum(!!str_count(x, letters))
char_ct_unique <- function(x) nchar(char_unique(x))
r_char_ct_unique <- function(x) length(unique(strsplit(x, "")[[1]]))

microbenchmark(stringr=str_char_ct_unique("banana"),
                  rcpp=char_ct_unique("banana"),
                     r=r_char_ct_unique("banana"),
               times=1000) -> mb

## Unit: microseconds
##     expr     min       lq       mean   median       uq     max neval cld
##  stringr 125.978 129.1765 139.271061 130.9415 139.3870 334.563  1000   c
##     rcpp   1.458   2.0160   3.002184   2.6345   3.1365  32.244  1000 a  
##        r   4.797   6.1070   8.292847   7.3380   8.0505  86.709  1000  b
```

[image]

Let's make a vectorized version of Cath's pure R solution (not bothering with the other one since it's way too constrained) and compare against a vector of small random strings:

```
library(random)
library(purrr)

char_ct_unique <- function(x) nchar(char_unique(x))
r_char_ct_unique <- function(x) map_int(map(x, function(x) unique(strsplit(x, "")[[1]])), length)

tst <- as.vector(randomStrings(n=100, len=20, unique=FALSE))

sum(char_ct_unique(tst) == r_char_ct_unique(tst))
## [1] 100

microbenchmark(rcpp=char_ct_unique(tst),
                  r=r_char_ct_unique(tst),
               times=1000) 

## Unit: microseconds
##  expr     min       lq      mean   median      uq      max neval cld
##  rcpp  53.643  56.2375  66.69311  60.2740  68.178  250.992  1000  a 
##     r 683.420 759.4070 952.14407 822.8905 922.710 6513.508  1000   b
```

[image]

And, now for the 10,000 character random string:

```
dat <- readLines("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hrbrmstr/f80b157b383134b37fb3/raw/534b4c79e7c51710c6db6961bc5dc5ec25c4242b/gistfile1.txt")
digest::digest(dat, "sha1", serialize=FALSE)
## [1] "6c6695dd2f314762c81e6e6891ec1c138a4f3a08"

nchar(dat)
## [1] 10000

char_ct_unique(dat) == r_char_ct_unique(dat)
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(rcpp=char_ct_unique(dat),
                  r=r_char_ct_unique(dat),
               times=1000)

## Unit: microseconds
##  expr     min      lq     mean  median      uq      max neval cld
##  rcpp  73.801 110.681 122.9091 118.330 139.373  308.602  1000  a 
##     r 377.556 430.703 533.9120 448.631 492.466 4275.568  1000   b
```

[image]

I forgot to do David's "fixed" version:

```
f_r_char_ct_unique <- function(x) map_int(map(x, function(x) unique(strsplit(x, "", fixed=TRUE)[[1]])), length)
```

and, let's make it more interesting:

```
dat <- c(dat, toupper(dat), tolower(dat))

microbenchmark(rcpp=char_ct_unique(dat),
                  r=r_char_ct_unique(dat),
                 fr=f_r_char_ct_unique(dat),
               times=1000) 

## Unit: microseconds
##  expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq       max neval
##  rcpp  218.299  284.143  331.319  332.281  358.1215   696.907  1000
##     r 1266.976 1442.460 1720.320 1494.167 1634.7870  5896.685  1000
##    fr 1260.027 1444.298 1769.664 1501.416 1652.8895 78457.729  1000
```

Comment: Who removed the dupe tag all of a sudden?

Comment: They are different questions.

Comment: I think the link was provided by @Cath, so it should be duplicate

Comment: You haven't benched `length(unique(strsplit(str1 , "", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]))` though. Also, benching on a 6 letters word is kind of odd IMO.

Comment: the dupe just doesn't count the number of different characters... would you mind benchmarking also the base R sol given in comments (just out of curiosity) ? (or the one given above by David. And on a 100000 characters word, that would probably give a better hint...)

Comment: all are in progress. i wanted to vectorize the C++ version first. stay tuned.