# String count in R

Tags: r, string

I am trying to construct a function similar to str_count.

```
fruit <- c("apple", "banana", "pear", "pineapple")
str_count(fruit, "a")
```

But rather than specifing the letter, the function should be able count the max number of duplicated characters.

So the output should be:

```
 Input    Output
 apple       2
 banana      3
  pear       0
```

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872838/r-count-the-number-of-unique-characters-in-that-string). but its written in c++.

Any ideas how I can do this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We split the 'fruit' into characters, check if there are any duplicates then get the `max` of the frequency or else return 0

```
sapply(strsplit(fruit, ""), function(x) if(anyDuplicated(x)) max(table(x)) else 0)
#[1] 2 3 0 3
```

Or slightly more compact

```
sapply(strsplit(fruit, ""), function(x) (anyDuplicated(x)!=0) * max(table(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. I didnt recall that I could do max(table(x)).